# Spring Cloud Gateway Global Exception handling and custom error response

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a custom filter that authenticates every request before calling the actual API using Spring Cloud  Gateway. Is there any way in Spring Cloud to handle exceptions centrally same as the Spring provide @ControllerAdvice? I want to handle exceptions globally and return custom error responses from the gateway.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1**: Write your custom `Exception` class by extending `org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException` class.

i.e.

```
public class InvalidTokenException extends ResponseStatusException {

    public InvalidTokenException(HttpStatus status) {
        super(status);
    }
}
```

**Step 2**: Write your custom ErrorAttributes class extending `DefaultErrorAttributes`

i.e.

```
@Component
public class GlobalErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes {
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(ServerRequest request, ErrorAttributeOptions options) {

        Map<String, Object> errorResponse = super.getErrorAttributes(request, options);

        //extract the status and put custom error message on the map
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.valueOf((Integer) errorResponse.get("status"));

        switch (status) {
            case BAD_REQUEST:
                errorResponse.put("message", "Your custom message");
                break;
            default:
                errorResponse.put("message", "Something went wrong!");
        }

        return errorResponse;
    }
}
```

**Step 3**: Write your CustomErrorWebExceptionHandler class by extending `AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler`

i.e.

```
@Component
@Order(-2)
public class GlobalErrorWebExceptionHandler extends AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler {


    public GlobalErrorWebExceptionHandler(GlobalErrorAttributes g,
                                          ApplicationContext applicationContext,
                                          ServerCodecConfigurer serverCodecConfigurer) {

        super(g, new WebProperties.Resources(), applicationContext);
        super.setMessageWriters(serverCodecConfigurer.getWriters());
        super.setMessageReaders(serverCodecConfigurer.getReaders());
    }

    @Override
    protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutingFunction(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.all(), this::renderErrorResponse);
    }

    private Mono<ServerResponse> renderErrorResponse (ServerRequest request) {
        Map<String, Object> errorPropertiesMap = getErrorAttributes(request, ErrorAttributeOptions.defaults());

        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.valueOf((Integer) errorPropertiesMap.get("status"));

        return ServerResponse.status(status)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(errorPropertiesMap));
    }
}
```

Now you can `throw` the custom exception from the filter.

i.e.

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<AuthenticationFilter.Config> {
public AuthenticationFilter() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {

        return ((exchange, chain) -> {
            String authHeader = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION).get(0);
            if (!validateToken(authHeader)) {
                throw new InvalidTokenException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }

            return chain.filter(exchange);
        });
    }

    public static class Config {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once an exception is thrown from your authentication filter, you can customize the error response by overriding the DefaultErrorAttributes class.

```java
@Component
public class GlobalErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes {


    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalErrorAttributes.class);

    public GlobalErrorAttributes() {
    }

    public GlobalErrorAttributes(boolean includeException) {
        super(includeException);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(ServerRequest request,
                                                  boolean includeStackTrace) {
        Throwable error = this.getError(request);
        logger.error("Error occured", error);
        MergedAnnotation<ResponseStatus> responseStatusAnnotation = MergedAnnotations
                .from(error.getClass(), MergedAnnotations.SearchStrategy.TYPE_HIERARCHY).get(ResponseStatus.class);
        HttpStatus errorStatus = findHttpStatus(error, responseStatusAnnotation);
        logger.info("errorStatus: {}", errorStatus);
        Map<String, Object> map = super.getErrorAttributes(request, includeStackTrace);
        String errorCode = getErrorCode(map, errorStatus);
        map.remove("timestamp");
        map.remove("path");
        map.remove("error");
        map.remove("requestId");
        map.put("errorCode", errorCode);
        return map;
    }

    private HttpStatus findHttpStatus(Throwable error, MergedAnnotation<ResponseStatus> responseStatusAnnotation) {
        if (error instanceof ResponseStatusException) {
            return ((ResponseStatusException) error).getStatus();
        }
        return responseStatusAnnotation.getValue("code", HttpStatus.class).orElse(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    private String getErrorCode(Map<String, Object> map, HttpStatus errorStatus) {
        String errorCode;
        switch (errorStatus) {
            case UNAUTHORIZED:
                errorCode = "401 UnAuthorized";
                break;
            case NOT_FOUND:
                logger.error("The url:{} is not found", map.get("path"));
                errorCode = "404 Not Found";
                map.put(MESSAGE, "NOT FOUND");
                break;
            case METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED:
                logger.error("Invalid HTTP Method type for the url: {}", map.get("path"));
                errorCode = "405 Method Not Allowed";
                break;
            default:
                logger.error("Unexpected error happened");
                logger.error("errorstatus is : {}", errorStatus);
                errorCode = "500 Internal Server Error";
                map.put(MESSAGE, "Unexpected Error");
        }
        return errorCode;
    }
}
```

The output will be something like below:

```java
{
   "status": 401,
   "message": "Invalid Access Token",
   "error_code": "401 UnAuthorized"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The spring cloud use Webflex is it reactive library,

you don't have `@ControllerAdvice` like `spring-boot`, but You can create a new Class to extend from `AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler`

The `AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler` has the responsibility for building an Exception response.

using the following example you can customize your Error Response as you need.

```
/**
 * @author: Abd-alrhman Alkraien
 * @since: 2023/08/22
 **/
@Component
@Order(-2)
@Log4j2
public class CustomError extends AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler {

    public CustomError(
            ErrorAttributes errorAttributes,
            ApplicationContext applicationContext,
            ServerCodecConfigurer serverCodecConfigurer) {
        super(errorAttributes, new WebProperties.Resources(), applicationContext);
        super.setMessageWriters(serverCodecConfigurer.getWriters());
        super.setMessageReaders(serverCodecConfigurer.getReaders());
    }

    /**
     * To route all requests with the specific response
     * @param errorAttributes attribute value.
     * @return will return ServerResponse Object for the client side.
     */
    @Override
    protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutingFunction(ErrorAttributes 
    errorAttributes) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.all(), 
    this::renderErrorResponse);
    }

    /**
     * To build response and set them using MONO, and Render Error Response
     * @param request has a request value.
     * @return will return Mono ServerResponse.
     */
    private Mono<ServerResponse> renderErrorResponse(ServerRequest request) {

        // To represent Error Attribute as a Map.
        Map<String, Object> errorPropertiesMap = getErrorAttributes(request, ErrorAttributeOptions.defaults());

        // To fetch response status code.
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.valueOf((Integer) errorPropertiesMap.get("status"));

        IbGenericResponse response;
        if (status.name().equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.name())) {

            // To handle any Not Found request.
            
            // build response.
            response = new IbGenericResponse(
                    BaseError
                            .builder()
                            .errorCode("-4" )
                            .errorDescription("Not found")
                            .results(status.name())
                            .isClean(false)
                            .errorDescriptionEn("Not Found Path".concat(request.path()))
                            .refOne( null)
                            .build(),
                    null,
                    null);
        } else {

            // To handle any InternalServer.

            // build response.
            response = new IbGenericResponse(
                    BaseError
                            .builder()
                            .errorCode("-1" )
                            .errorDescription("")
                            .results(status.name())
                            .isClean(false)
                            .errorDescriptionEn("Internal Server Error".concat(request.path()))
                            .refOne( null)
                            .build(),
                    null,
                    null);
        }
        
        // return your server response after building it.
        return ServerResponse.status(status)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(response));
    }
}
```